# Matrix subset dimensions

Tags: r

This is a very trivial example, but I do have real data where I am experiencing this particular problem. For simplicity, let's say I have a matrix in R called x, 20 rows x 3 columns

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow=20, ncol=3)
```

Then I take a subset of the matrix, for example, using index i, which can be a single integer, for example i <- 4, or multiple integers, for example i <- c(4:7), depending on the algorithm iterations (in other words, in one iteration i may be a single integer and in the next iteration i is multiple integers) and I'd like to know the size of the resulting subset

```
xsubset <- x[i,]
```

Then I use the dim command

```
dim(xsubset)
```

and I get the result: NULL

What do I have to do to determine the number of rows and columns in xsubset?

Comment: It should be `x[1, ]` or similar as i is not defined.

Comment: You are looking for drop=FALSE, by the way: `x[1, , drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: If you read the text, the value of i is well defined

Anyway, `drop=FALSE` seems to work